# Nullpointerexception whith Color class

Tags: java, graphics

```
private void drawSquare (Graphics g, int row, int col,
        Tetrominoes shape){

    Color[] colors={new Color(0,0,0), new Color(204,102,102),
            new Color(102,204,102), new Color(102,102,204),
            new Color(204,204,102), new Color(204,102,204),
            new Color(102,204,204), new Color(218,170,0)
    };
    int x = col * squareWhidth();
    int y = row * squareHeight();
    Color color = colors[shape.ordinal()];  // **** NullPointerException here ****
    g.setColor(color);
    g.fillRect(x + 1, y + 1, squareWhidth() - 2,
    squareHeight() - 2);
    g.setColor(color.brighter());
    g.drawLine(x, y + squareHeight() - 1, x, y);
    g.drawLine(x, y, x + squareWhidth() - 1, y);
    g.setColor(color.darker());
    g.drawLine(x + 1, y + squareHeight() - 1,
    x + squareWhidth() - 1, y + squareHeight() - 1);
    g.drawLine(x + squareWhidth() - 1,
    y + squareHeight() - 1,
    x + squareWhidth() - 1, y + 1);
}
```

Throws me a  nullpointerexception when I run the program and the terminal reference me in this line: `Color color = colors[shape.ordinal()];`

Comment: Can you share the code for `Tetrominoes` pleae?

Comment: And how are you calling `drawSquare (...)`? Are you passing a null reference into its arguments when calling it? Is shape null? And where are you calling it?

Answer (score 2):

If the NullPointerException incriminates this line: `Color color = colors[shape.ordinal()];`then it logically implies that your shape object is null at that point. You should debug the call to drawSquare and check what `shape`object the calling method is passing into it.